# Cypress verify API request

Tags: cypress

I want to verify if the API request contains what it needs to contain, but not sure what I am doing wrong as I have always this error:

```
cy.wait() timed out waiting 5000ms for the 1st request to the route: apiCheck. No request ever occurred.
```

I have a link in the main menu, after clicking that link the new page opens and API call is iniciated immediately http://localhost:8081/currencies

So in Cypress I have this:

```
 cy.get('ul li[title="Menu item"]>a').click();

  cy.intercept({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/currencies',
      }).as('apiCheck')

      cy.wait('@apiCheck').then((interception) => {
      expect(interception.response.statusCode).to.equal(200);
expect(interception.response.body[0]).to.have.property('geographyName', 'EMEA')
      })
```

As you can see from Cypress test runner screenshot, the request is there and has status 200, but still it says no request ever occurred.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ah, well, seems I need to call cy.intercept before the link is clicked, then it seems working.